# Internal frame pass variable back java

Tags: java, swing, jframe, parameter-passing, jinternalframe

As a newbie, I struggle with this basic problem. 
I have an internal frame that opens using a simple button on my main frame.

I would like to be able to get the value of one variable from my internal frame and use it for calculations on my main frame.

INTERNAL FRAME:

```
private void jSlider1StateChanged(javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent evt) {                                      
int x = jSlider1.getValue();
}
```

which works perfectly fine.

MAIN FRAME:

```
int x = INTERNAL_FRAME.x;  //ERROR: Cannot find variable

int x = INTERNAL_FRAME.jSlider1.getValue(); //ERROR: jslider has private access
```

How can I pass x to my MAIN FRAME?

I have tried the following:

INTERNAL FRAME //action performed

```
new MAIN_FRAME(x);
```

MAIN_FRAME

```
public MAIN_FRAME(x){
double var = x;
initComponents();
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

There are several solutions:

Pass a mainFrame reference to the internal frame, and call a method of the main frame from the internal frame when the slider state changes. This couples the internal frame to the main frame though

```
public class MainFrame {
    public void doSomethingWithX(int x) {
        // ...
    }

    public void showInternalFrame() {
        InternalFrame f = new InternalFrame(this);
        // ...
    }
}

public class InternalFrame {
    private MainFrame mainFrame;

    public InternalFrame(MainFrame mainFrame) {
        this.mainFrame = mainFrame;
    }

    private void jSlider1StateChanged(ChangeEvent evt) {
        int x = jSlider1.getValue();
        mainFrame.doSomethingWithX();
    }
}
```

Or pass a reference to some interface (XValueChangeListener for example) from the main frame to the internal frame, and call the xValueChanged() method from the internal frame when x changes. This decouples the internal frame from the main frame.

```
public interface XValueChangeListener {
    void xValueChanged(int newValueOfX);
}

public class MainFrame {
    private void doSomethingWithX(int x) {
        // ...
    }

    public void showInternalFrame() {
        InternalFrame f = new InternalFrame(new XValueChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void xValueChanged(int newValueOfX) {
                doSomethingWithX(x);
            }
        });
        // ...
    }
}

public class InternalFrame {
    private XValueChangeListener listener;

    public InternalFrame(XValueChangeListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    private void jSlider1StateChanged(ChangeEvent evt) {
        int x = jSlider1.getValue();
        listener.xValueChanged(x);
    }
}
```

You could use the last solution with standard Java events if you want (like ChangeListener or PropertyChangeListener).